# How Do I put generated string into a Form action and input

Tags: javascript, forms, action

basically I need to generate random strings and then I need to make it variables that will end up needing to be made into one long link that will then be posted into the form with post method and input(described below)

What I need:
I need to a php/javascript that would generate random terms (three different functions) "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ" 
"0123456789"
"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-_"

and then I need you to put an example in their 
for instance
var text=randomstring(3);
so I can see how it is done and how I can add more if needed.

Then I basically need a script that will be sent as a request
and I need to be able to edit the code getting sent 
for instance 
`"'https://google.com/' + text + '"`

Then I need a iframe hidden
`<iframe style="display:none" id="test" name="test"></iframe>`
and I need it to have a `<form name="" action="https://example.com/' + text + '"`
and then the method="POST"> and then
input (hidden) with a name and value
(I would need to be able to change the info in the input with the generated things)

Comment: Instead of having the form submit data, you can use Javascript so when the button is pressed, it will submit data through the click instead of on the form submit

Comment: how do I insert generated strings into a form action though?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myForm").action = "form_action.asp";
```

Give your form an ID and replace "myForm" with the ID, then with the event, call that piece of code, it will change the action property.

If you want to add a parameter to the action just do

```
var curAction = document.getElementById("myForm").action;
document.getElementById("myForm").action = curAction + "?id=1";
```